# Remap component listeners to child components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings, vuejs3

In Vue2/JavaScript I had this computed property for remapping component listeners to child components based on prefix:

```js
inputPortListeners() {
  return reduce(
    this.$listeners,
    (listeners, listener, name) => {
      if (!name.startsWith('input-')) return listeners;
      listeners[name.slice('input-'.length)] = (e) => listener.call(this, e, this.node.id, e.target.dataset.index);
      return listeners;
    },
    {}
  );
},
```

Now that I am migrating to Vue3/TypeScript I'm having trouble migrating this computed property as well. What I have so far is this:

```
type Listeners = Record<string, (e: unknown)=>void>;
const inputPortListeners = computed(() => {
  return Object.keys(attrs).reduce<Listeners>((listeners, name: string) => {
    if (!name.startsWith('onInput')) return listeners;
    listeners[name.replace('onInput', '')] = (e: unknown) => attrs[name].call(this, e, this.node.id, e.target.dataset.index);
    return listeners;
  }, {});
});
```

The problematic line is this one:

```
(e: unknown) => attrs[name].call(this, e, props.node.id, e.target.dataset.index);
```

because `attrs` does not have a strong type and `e` is unknown so cannot get `e.target.dataset.index`.

What are my options to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrs` (from the [`setup()`'s `context` argument](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#context)) is a [`Data`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/47f488350c53db2bd9682e0c27a4f1dbcdab162a/packages/runtime-core/src/component.ts#L171), which is [defined as](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/47f488350c53db2bd9682e0c27a4f1dbcdab162a/packages/runtime-core/src/component.ts#L64):

```js
Record<string, unknown>
```

So, `attrs[name]` is `unknown`, which in your case requires type assertion to use as a function:

```js
(attrs[name] as Function).call(...)
```

Similarly, `e` is `unknown`, but it doesn't need to be. The `e` here is really an `Event`, so you can switch from `(e: unknown)` to `(e: Event)`:

```js
type Listeners = Record<string, (e: Event)=>void>;
//...
listeners[name.replace('Input', '')] = (e: Event) => {...};
```

`Event` has a `target` property that is [defined as](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9d443b7/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5071):

```js
EventTarget | null
```

However, `EventTarget` does not have `dataset`, which [comes from `HTMLElement`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9d443b7/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L7860). You can use type assertion to `HTMLElement`, as the `target` is presumably `<input>` (based on the `input` event name):

```js
(e.target as HTMLElement)?.dataset.index
```

The resulting code should be:

```js
type Listeners = Record<string, (e: Event)=>void>;
const inputPortListeners = computed(() => {
  return Object.keys(attrs).reduce<Listeners>((listeners, name: string) => {
    if (!name.startsWith('onInput')) return listeners;
    listeners[name.replace('Input', '')] = (e: Event) => (attrs[name] as Function).call(this, e, null, (e.target as HTMLElement)?.dataset.index);
    return listeners;
  }, {});
});
```